# Google Analytics OptOut Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, syntax-error

I tried to implement the GoogleAnalytics Optout possibillity, because the german
dataprotection law forces me to do that.

I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaProperty = 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X';
var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;

if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
    window[disableStr] = true;
}

function gaOptout() {
    document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC;
    path=/';
    window[disableStr] = true;
}
</script>
```

If I look into the chrome developer console I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

The error is in this line

```
function gaOptout() {
```

and marked is the {

I tried it a few times allready and sometimes it is this bracket and sometimes it is an other {.

What is wrong? Any ideas? I'm searching a half day and tried so many solutions from the web. But nothing works...

If it is important I implement google analytics with a hard coded Global Site Tag (gtag)

Comment: No `'` at the end of the `document.cookie = ` line.  It's acting like `path` is a new variable.  Probably just want to get rid of the return(s), so it reads `... 2099 23:59:59 UTC;path=/';`

Comment: If the newlines are required in the cookie value, read [Creating Multiline Strings in JavaScript](/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for help!
Not the ' was the problem. It was the "enter" behind the ; in this line. I thougt in a string the enter has no function. But without the enter it is working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was the "enter" behind the ; in line

```
document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC;
```

it should be

```
document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC;path=/';
```